# SQL query to update a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query which throws error-SQL gives error

> ORA-01427 single row sub-query returns multiple rows

in Oracle 8.

```
UPDATE STG1_HFHS_ENR_EMP_ROSTER_2005 A
SET 
A.BUSINESS_UNIT =
( SELECT t.BUSINESS_UNIT
FROM STG1_HFHS_ENR_EMP_ROS_2005_TMP t, STG1_HFHS_ENR_EMP_ROSTER_2005 s
WHERE t.ID = s.ID )
```

Could you please help me in correcting the above error. I have to UPDATE one column `"A.BUSINESS_UNIT =`

Comment: Your subselect returns more than one row. You need to restrict it with an extra clause in `WHERE` or with a `LIMIT`. What are you trying to get in the subselect?

Comment: I have to select the .BUSINESS_UNIT from the inner query and update the outer query

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UPDATE STG1_HFHS_ENR_EMP_ROSTER_2005 A
SET 
A.BUSINESS_UNIT =
( SELECT t.BUSINESS_UNIT
FROM STG1_HFHS_ENR_EMP_ROS_2005_TMP t
WHERE t.ID = A.ID AND ROWNUM < 2)
```

Comment: Thanks.But now we get another error in the subquery at SELECT TOP 1 t.BUSINESS_UNIT  which says ORA000923:From key word not found where expect.  ** It stops at TOP 1. I am using Oracle 8

Comment: @VMAtm: What's the purpose of that "ORDER BY t.ID"?

Comment: @Rob van Wijk We are getting only first row value, so we will need the order clause, wouldn't we?

Comment: Thanks again.but error again.  UPDATE STG1_HFHS_ENR_EMP_ROSTER_2005 A
SET
A.BUSINESS_UNIT =
( SELECT STG1_HFHS_ENR_EMP_ROS_2005_TMP.BUSINESS_UNIT
FROM STG1_HFHS_ENR_EMP_ROS_2005_TMP,STG1_HFHS_ENR_EMP_ROSTER_2005
WHERE STG1_HFHS_ENR_EMP_ROSTER_2005.ID = STG1_HFHS_ENR_EMP_ROS_2005_TMP.ID AND R
 order by STG1_HFHS_ENR_EMP_ROS_2005_TMP.BUSINESS_UNIT DESC)               
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: Your code is not equal to mine. Also there is error in `AND` clause.

Comment: @VMATM: the order by doesn't hurt (only performance wise a bit), but it suggests functionality that just isn't there. Please execute a "select * from emp where rownum < 2 order by ename" and see for yourself.

Comment: @Rob van Wijk Removed ORDER BY

Comment: I tried directly your code only-                                                    UPDATE STG1_HFHS_ENR_EMP_ROSTER_2005 A
SET 
A.BUSINESS_UNIT =
( SELECT t.BUSINESS_UNIT
FROM STG1_HFHS_ENR_EMP_ROS_2005_TMP t
WHERE t.ID = A.ID AND ROWNUM < 2
ORDER BY t.ID )   Error is - 000907 it gets STUCK at ORDER saying "MISSING right Parenthesis

Comment: @All, the ORDER BY in the subquery is what is throwing the 907 error. It's not allowed in this context.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE stg1_hfhs_enr_emp_roster_2005 a
SET 
a.business_unit =
(SELECT business_unit
 FROM (SELECT business_unit
       FROM stg1_hfhs_enr_emp_ros_2005_tmp 
       ORDER BY ... -- some clause that puts the most relevant business_unit as first
      ) 
 WHERE id = a.id
   AND ROWNUM < 2);
```

Unfortunately I don't have access to Oracle 8 to test this. 
Two layers of inline views are required to ORDER and limit rowcount. Also, you can't directly reference table "a" inside the deepest inline view (some stupid Oracle restriction), so it is needed in the middle view.

Comment: What does the rownum < 2 does?

Comment: @rohit Guarantees that only the first row is returned in case of multiple rows. It prevents "ORA-01427 single row sub-query returns multiple rows"